# Count statement in SQL slows down the query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, query-optimization

`item_tag_map` has two column `item_id` and `tag_id` and both of them have index.

Here's a data sample:

```
item_id     tag_id
1           1
1           3
4           7
1           5
3           1
3           8
6           8
10          4
```

Now I want to obtain item ids which have tags 1,2,3,5 and sort the result by the total count of all tags.

Here's a result sample:

```
item_id     count(m.tag_id)
1           3
3           1
```

The SQL I tried was:

```
SELECT m.item_id,count(m.tag_id) from item_tag_map AS m
WHERE tag_id in(1,2,3,5)
GROUP BY m.item_id
ORDER BY count(m.tag_id)
LIMIT 10
```

There're about 10k rows in this table and the query was very slow. I tried to remove all `count` statement, then it became very fast than before.

Why would `count` slow down this query? How to optimize this query to make it fast?

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say? It's almost certainly the "ORDER BY" statement which is causing the delay - but the only way to be sure is to EXPLAIN the querry.

Comment: @NevilleK I don't think it's order by because only adding `count` in select count(m.tag_id) from ... slows down it.And here's the explain result:`id:1;select_type:simple;table:m;type:index;possible_keys:tag_id;key:item_id;key_len:4;ref:null;extra:using where using temporary using filesort`

Comment: Have you tried what Kali suggests? The explain suggests that the query is using a temporary table (to store the result of the select) and then a file sort on that temporary table (to achieve the "order by"). It also suggests that it's not using the index on TAG_ID - which is odd.

Comment: @NevilleK I tried `USE INDEX(tag_id)` to force it using `tag_id` but not `item_id` as index, it became a lot more faster than before which still costed 2s to finish the query.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily the index which is causing the slow down. Can you remove the order by clause and tell us if the query is faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of `ORDER BY COUNT(m.tag_id)`.
MySQL needs to fetch all rows (ie. do a full table scan) to calculate the count for each value of `item_id`.

MySQL is not able to use the index in this case. (as you may realize when looking at `EXPLAIN SELECT ..`)

When you remove the `COUNT()` from the `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL is able to use the index for sorting.

---

One possible solution for this would be to create a [materialized view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view), where the DBMS caches the count of `tag_id` values per `item_id` in a seperate table.

MySQL doesn't support materialized views natively, but you can simulate them: 
You can initially create the table once using the query in question (`INSERT INTO tag_counts SELECT ...`) and then keep it updated using `ON [INSERT | DELETE]` triggers.
Alternatively, there is a third party software named [FlexViews](http://code.google.com/p/flexviews/) which automates this process for you.

That's how i kept my multi-million-rows-per-week statistics database reactive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'll consider your method but I don't think you explained the reason well. I posted the `explain` result in the question comment which suggested `type:index;possible_keys:tag_id;key:item‌​_id;key_len:4`. I think that meant it used indexes.

Comment: @LotusH no that does *not* mean it's using an index. You must look at the "extra" column: `using where using temporary using filesort`. This actually means what i said: MySQL is doing a full table scan. "possible_keys" just means that there is a potential key to use. It does not mean it *can* be used. That would be indicated by "using index" in the "extra" column.